# What do you thing about "In France, there is a Chinese proverb that says ..."?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

What do you think about:

> In France, there is a Chinese proverb that says "..."?

Is it just a joke or something serious?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is a Chinese Proverb that is only used by the subgroup of chinese speakers in france, this could be totally serious.
Otherwise, at least in Germany I know people saying "Old chinese proverb!" jokingly, often for some kind of common sense-based proverb-like thing they just made up.

Comment: Add the "In France" comment, and it's supposed to be even sillier.